# How to get a specific value in this json

Tags: json

I have question, I hava a json with some information and I need to get a specific value, for example the Location, I had created a function but it doesn´t work fine, I get this error message about the " "

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
"location"        : "Austin-Bergstrom International Airport,
```

The function is this one

```
function lee_json() {
    var temp = ('http://df9e7c46aa4c80573717-1199cc892ebab574a120721e4772cd8b.r11.cf2.rackcdn.com/services/aus.json');      
    temp2 = temp.location;
    alert(temp2);
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(temp.location);
}
```

and the Json is this one

```
{
    "location"        : "Austin-Bergstrom International Airport, Tx",
    "city"            : "Austin",
    "state"           : "Tx",
    "dewPointC"       : 4.4,
    "visibilityMiles" : 10,
    "rainChance"      : "10%"
}
```

What can be the problem ?

Regards,

Comment: Does `temp` contain only the URL of the JSON object?

Comment: @MathieuImbert That's what it looks like to me...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you have to retrieve the content of URL, parse it, then you'll be able to access the JSON object. And you won't be able to do that unless your script runs on the same domain as the JSON file is hosted on.

Comment: @Joe the function that you have pasted doesn't request the json object or parse it. Post the code at the line where you actually get that error SyntaxError: invalid label
Can you confirm if you are running this on the same domain where the JSON is hosted?

Answer (score 0):

try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx this might be the kind of answer you're looking

if i assume you are using jquery you can use this

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Hi delroekid and thank you for you answer, I checked the first link and I saw that I can use this
var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(contact.surname + ", " + contact.firstname);

But how Can I add the URL of my json ?

In the second one I tried this 
$.getJSON('http://df9e7c46aa4c80573717-1199cc892ebab574a120721e4772cd8b.r11.cf2.rackcdn.com/services/aus.json', function(data) {document.write(data.city); }); but I didn´t see anything

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 1) you are running this on the same domain where the json is hosted, 2) you have jquery, 3) the result is a json object, not an array, this is a legit example of getting a field:

```
function getData(aLink) {
       $.getJSON(aLink, 
       function(data)    {
           console.log(data.location); 
        }); 
}
getData("http://df9e7c46aa4c80573717-1199cc892ebab574a120721e4772cd8b.r11.cf2.rackcdn.com/services/aus.json");
```

Comment: Hi ile, let me tell you that..
1) this script and the jsong are not in the same host
2) Yes
3) Well. I received this information as I mencioned in the begin of this post. I think that this is a json,
{
"location"        : "Austin-Bergstrom International Airport, Tx",
"city"            : "Austin",
"state"           : "Tx",
"dewPointC"       : 4.4,
"visibilityMiles" : 10,
"rainChance"      : "10%"
}

Comment: Because of 1) my answer won't be very helpful, but I will keep it in case somebody with a same host scenario comes across it. Fyi - you can confirm this is the json format by simply pasting the link in the address bar of a browser (at least Chrome). That is the indeed correct the correct json (object) data.